# Organic impact fall-off after featuring on Play store

Tags: google-play, sales

I have an app on the Google Play store, and it has been featured under Strategic games, up to the ~15th place for some days.

Before the featuring, my organic acquisition rate was growing up to 3000 installs/day.

Now that the featuring is finished, my organic acquisition rate has declined to a new level of 300 installs/day.

Is this something to be expected?
Can it grow back to 3000 players/day like it was before?

[image: Graph of store listing acquisitions]

Comment: The graph is a bit hard to read, but it looks like ~20 days with 12k players a day. The end of the graph has as well a rather short sampling size of 1? day. It might in the short term the market is just saturated for your target group  and just goes back by itself. Or you might need to have a different ad campaign. Or more content

Comment: I forgot to mention that all the acquisition is 100% organic, I don't do any paid acquisition ATM.